# Tablesorter not working in Wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tablesorter

I want to use tablesorter in my wordpress plugin.

This is how my table looks like

```
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped" style="font-size:80%;" id="table_id">
       <thead align="left">
         <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
            <th style="min-width:6em;">col3</th>
            <th style="min-width:4em";>col4</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
   <tbody> 
   </tbody> 
</table>
```

The table rows are added later dynamically.

In the PHP file I used

```
  wp_enqueue_script('tablesorter', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery.tablesorter.js', array('jquery172'));
```

In the javascript file I used

```
  $("#table_id").tablesorter();
```

I copied the file jquery.tablesorter.js into my js directory. But nothing happens. Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this specific helper function for wordpress to make it work?

http://webjawns.com/2009/11/jquery-tablesorter-helper-function-for-wordpress/

```
/**
 * Make all tables with the specified identifier sortable using the jQuery Tablesorter
plugin.
 *
 * @uses wp_enqueue_script() To enqueue the jQuery Tablesorter script.
 *
 * @param string $identifier jQuery selector (.sortable, #element_id, table, etc.)
 * @param array $args Default is empty string. Array of arguments to pass to
 $.tablesorter()
 * @return void
 */
function make_table_sortable($identifier, $args = '') {
global $sortable_tables;

if ( in_array($identifier, (array)$sortable_tables) )
    return;

wp_enqueue_script('jquery-tablesorter');

$sortable_tables[] = array(
    'identifier' => $identifier,
    'args'       => $args
);

add_action('admin_print_footer_scripts', '_make_table_sortable');
}

function _make_table_sortable() {
global $sortable_tables;

if ( count( (array)$sortable_tables ) <= 0 )
    return;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
foreach ($sortable_tables as $sortable_table) {
    if ( !is_array($sortable_table['args']) ) {
        $arguments = '';
    } else {
        $arguments = '{';

        $args_count = sizeof($sortable_table['args']);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($sortable_table['args'] as $k => $v) {
            $arguments .= $k . ': ' . $v;
            if (++$i != $args_count) $arguments .= ', ';
        }

        $arguments .= '}';
    }
?>
$('<?php echo esc_js($sortable_table['identifier']); ?>').tablesorter(<?php 
echo esc_js($arguments); ?>);
<?php } ?>
</script>
<?php
}
```

Below exemplifies usage of the make_table_sortable() function:

```
// Sort tables with class 'sortable', first and second columns in ascending 
// order with first taking precedence.
make_table_sortable('.sortable', array('sortList' => '[[0,0], [1,0]]'));

// Sort table with ID 'sortable', first column in ascending order. Turn debugging on.
make_table_sortable('#sortable', array('sortList' => '[[1,0]]', 'debug' => 'true'));
```

Maybe this will help you to sort the issues out a little better.

Comment: also put content in answer